# How to salvage data from a running python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I created this script to scrape tweets from twitter, however I forgot to add a while True loop to the saver function and the data hasn't been recorded. It is still in memory whatsoever and i'm wondering if there is anything I can do to save it some how.

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from threading import Thread

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

url = input("Enter an URL >>>")
FileName = input("What to save as >>>")

tweets_list = []

browser.get(url)
sleep(1)

body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

def saver():
    sleep(2)
    global tweets_list
    with open(FileName,"w+") as f:
        for i in tweets_list:
            try:
                f.write(i.replace("\n",",")+"\n")
                print(i)
            except:
                print("ERROR"*99)

T1 = Thread(target=saver,daemon=True)
T1.start()

while True:
    for _ in range(500):
        body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

    tweets = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("tweet-text")

    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.text.replace("\n\n","\n") in tweets_list:
            pass
        elif tweet.text.replace("\n\n","\n") not in tweets_list:
            tweets_list.append(tweet.text.replace("\n\n","\n"))
```

Comment: You can probably `pickle` it. Look into how pickle works, I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Joe I looked it up and i'm not sure what pickle can do to help me now.

Comment: ahh, I re-read you question and I see now. I think you meant 'is it' instead of 'it is'. I was thinking you had the data and needed to save it.

Comment: @Joe I do have the data, stored in the tweets_list it just isn't saved anywhere.

Comment: Oh then use pickle, it allows you to serialize and save that data into a file. You can then use it to reload the data again when you need it. This way you are not wasting memory trying to hold all the data, or scraping for it over and over again

Comment: @Joe How would I do what you suggesting?

Comment: its hard to say without seeing you data. I would possibly convert the data to a `pandas` dataframe then use pandas to pickle it

Comment: @Joe my data is just a list of tweets in a list. So basically just a list of strings.

Comment: What would be the easiest for you, especially because your still learning, would be to save the output into a text file. Save it as a CSV and it will be easy to parse when you reload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used control-c to stop the program, then formatted, and wrote the list to a file using the python shell.